# eliminar tabla de un esquema en oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, table

Como puedo eliminar una tabla de un esquema en **Oracle** mediante **sql** plus por favor?
intente esto pero no me da

```
delete nombre_de_la_tabla from ALL_ALL_TABLES  WHERE OWNER='BIOSTAR2_TA_USER' ;
```

Comment: como puedo eliminar una tabla de un esquema en Oracle mediante sql plus por favor? o como puedo eliminar todo el esquema por favor

Comment: usa el boton [edit]. Arregla la pregunta. Asi como esta no se entiende nada. que problema tenes?

Comment: Creo que te faltó agregar al código y/o lo que intentaste hacer.

Comment: No hay que intentar borrar de los catálogos de Oracle, que muchas veces son vistas de otros datos. Con borrarla usando `esquema.tabla`, es suficiente. Para tus preguntas, además, procura añádir qué respuesta te dió la ejecución de tu código, pues "no funcionó" no suele dar idea de lo que sucede

Answer (score 1):

la sintaxis es:

```
DROP TABLE [nombre_del_esquema].table_name
[ CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ]
[ PURGE ];
```

Tomado de: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/drop_table.php